# ER schema generalization resolution

Tags: database, attributes, entity-relationship

I have the following ER schema and I want to resolve the generalization but I don't know what is the best or the optimal solution.

My first idea was to make the MEDIA entity disappear and to connect the COPIA entity with the other two entities (VIDEO and LIBRO), but I think I cannot do this because of the primary keys, and the weak entity COPIA.

Otherwise I thought about inglobing VIDEO and LIBRO into MEDIA but in this way there are gonna be to much empty attributes (if the media is a movie, all the book(libro) attributes are going to be empty).

The last thing shoul be to keep all four the entities and just connect them (erasing the generalization) but in that case, what could become a good primary key for LIBRO and VIDEO?

[image: ER Schema]

So, how to solve it in the best way?

PS: Video = video, libro = book, media = media, copia = copy

Answer (score 1):

MEDIA (**Media-Code**, Title, Genre)

VIDEO (**Video-Code**, **Media-Code**, Duration)
VIDEO-COPY (**Video-Code**, **Copy-Code**)

BOOK (**Book-Code**, **Media-Code**, Author)
BOOK-COPY (**Book-Code**, **Copy-Code**)

COPY (**Copy-Code**, CopyType, Available)  [copy type would be either book or video]

```
       ---< BOOK ----< BOOK-COPY  >----
      |                                |
MEDIA -                                ---- COPY
      |                                |
       ---< VIDEO ---< VIDEO-COPY  >----
```